# ASP.NET 5.0 / ASP.NET Core 1.0 and Entity Framework 6 on Mac OS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core

Because of the lack of supported databases and the unfinished state of Entity Framework 7.0 / EF Core 1.0, I try to use Entity Framework 6 with ASP.NET 5.0 / ASP.Net Core 1.0 on Mac with PostgreSQL.

I removed the dnxcore50 framework, because it don't support Entity Framework 6.

My project.json looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "DbTestWebAPI"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

It's a empty Web API project with the default ValuesController.cs.
If I run `dnx web` I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The current runtime target framework is not compatible with 'DbTestWebAPI'.
Current runtime target framework: 'DNXCore,Version=v5.0 (dnxcore50)'
 Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16231
 Type:         CoreClr
 Architecture: x64
 OS Name:      Darwin
 OS Version:   10.11
 Runtime Id:   osx.10.11-x64

Please make sure the runtime matches a framework specified in project.json
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.DefaultHost.GetEntryPoint(String applicationName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, String appBase, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
```

Any ideas what I doing wrong? Or it is not possible to run this on a Mac / Linux with Mono?

My output for 'dnvm list':

```
Active Version              Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------              ------- ------------ --------------- -----
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x64          darwin          default
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    mono                 linux/osx       
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x64          darwin          default
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    mono                 linux/osx
```

Comment: I guess you have installed the coreclr version of the runtime via dnvm, but not the clr (full .net/mono framewokr) version. What does `dnvm list` outputs?

Comment: If there is no clr version installed, you can install it via `dnvm upgrade -r clr -a x64` (-a is for architecture, x64 or x86)

Comment: @Tseng If I execute 'nvm upgrade -r clr -a x64", I get the following error: `Error: Could not find latest version from feed https://www.nuget.org/api/v2`

Comment: Seems the clr is just for windows. `dnvm upgrade latest -r mono` should do. You also need to install mono yourself, as this only installs the dnx runtime for mono, not mono itself.

Comment: ASP.NET 5 RC1 should work with Mono 4.0.1 (the docker image is based on mono 4.0.1 image so I guess it's supposed to work with it). Dunno about compatibility with other mono versions

Comment: @Tseng Thanks, Tseng! I get it working with 'dnvm install latest -r mono -a x64'. But after I close the terminal and call again 'dnx web' in a new terminal window, I get the same error :-/ . After execute 'dnvm install latest -r mono -a x64' again, it works until the next restart of the terminal. Why the changes are not persistent?

Comment: To make a DNVM change persistent you'll have to us the -p switch. (https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm/issues/262)

Comment: @MarcelE: For "install" you need to switch, using the "upgrade" command should install and make it permanent by default